# How to get the number of pictures in a tif file using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a stack of images in a tiff file. How do I get the number of pictures in a this file using Matlab?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`imfinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html) from the Image Processing Toolbox determine the total number of images in your stack.  `imfinfo` will return an array of structures where each element in this structure gives you information about each image in your TIFF stack.  The special case is when you only have a single image and in this case you should only see a single structure that contains information about the image.

Using `imfinfo` is the most efficient way to ascertain how many images are in your stack in comparison to manually loading in the TIFF yourself and seeing how many images there are in the stack by examining the third dimension of the array that is loaded in.

Specifically, simply do:

```
info = imfinfo('...'); % Place path to file inside single quotes
num_images = numel(info);
```

`num_images` will contain the total number of images in your stack.

If you want more information about this, you can take a look at Steve Eddins' blog here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/04/02/matlab-r2009a-imread-and-multipage-tiffs/